# How to embed a google spreadsheet into ckeditor?

Tags: google-sheets, ckeditor, spreadsheet, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor v4 in my website.
If i try to embed spreadsheet with the help of iframe code(provided by google sheet)
Then its not working on ckeditor.

Can anyone help me how to embed google sheet into ckeditor with the help of Iframe code.

Comment: please provide us with what you have already intergrated - block of iFrame's code, error message and so on.

Comment: <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSF04Hvdoh0rn20H8iXe35u4n99AN0GvtCheelxWeK3G7lhlzo8377DN4uBI9tf-UVJdEWA2eY-n1Jg/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>

Comment: i am using ckeditor on backend of server and output will show on android native app. but i am unable to embed sheet in ckeditor.

Comment: I'm not sure that additing/embedding Google Spreadsheets can possible via iframe. But I found this 'Paste from Google Docs'  CKEditor's plugin: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/pastefromgdocs. Perhaps this could solve your problem. Please check it and add feedback about this.

Comment: thank you for you suggestions. i knew about it but i want to embed sheet. my plan is to change data via sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ckeditor is not showing embedded google document in native android app.